# The Death Cure and Newt

Tags: the-maze-runner

I’m confused in the Death Cure. So we know Thomas is the cure at this point. Because his blood cells where able to not slow down the virus but to destroy it completely. We know this because he cured Brenda. Which once Teresa figured it that he was the cure then she started talking over the intercom across the whole city. So at this point I believe he knows he’s the cure and he’s still with Newt at this point. So that brings me to my question.

- Since Thomas is known as the cure why wouldn’t he have just let Newt bite him once after Newt turned crank then knock him out and then carry him away to safety?

Comment: Just because he knows that, doesn't mean he's comfortable with letting someone bite him.

Comment: But wouldn’t you do that for a friend? I mean theoretically speaking Thomas would be saving his life. That would be something you could look back on later in life and be proud of.

Comment: Would a bite work? Is Newt too far gone? Curing one person doesn’t mean a universal cure at any stage. Plus, if one crank bites him, will the rest swarm and eat him? I read these a while ago, need to go back and re read!

Comment: Lol I’m the movie Newt was the only crank there. And since Thomas was a pure cure and his cells attacked the virus it should cure him. At least that’s what I believe.

Comment: How do I find that chat???

Comment: Oh haha, I thought this was about Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them! >.<

Answer (score 2):

Why would you let someone bite you? The possibility of it working seems... slim to say the least, my reasoning behind this is that cranks don't act like vampires.

Yeah, biting him might let Newt consume some of his blood but it wont directly go to his bloodstream - that's why the **injected** Brenda with Thomas' blood, not gave it to her to drink or something. Sure, it would at some point go into his bloodstream but that wouldn't happen that quickly, and I'm pretty sure you don't wanna stick around in a burning city possibly filled with cranks.

My reasoning behind this is because I'm pretty sure the virus takes place into the bloodstream (judging by the pulsing blue veins being a symptom of it).

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer a bit, to make it more fit to what's described in the [help] and avoid it being deleted, as this reads like a reasonable answer. Just make sure to write the next ones with a bit more proper formatting :)